# .bat скрипты, их возможности

Tags: bat

Можно ли с помощью bat скрипта определить состояние tcp соединения?(если я знаю порт по которому может идти обмен данными)
т.е. позволяют ли инструменты(доступные команды) .bat файлов проверять сетевые подключения?

Comment: @mayar уже ответил. Старый рецепт солдатского кушанья -- "каша из топора". Но если взять юниксовый классический bourne shell, то без shell-утилит он очень мало чего может

Comment: Вообщем я так понял нельзя. Хочешь проверить соединение пиши приложение для проверки соединения и бери от него результат.
Всем спасибо

Comment: @maxmail ну зачем же так-то. Правды вы не написали, что значит "состояние", но для простейших случаев netstat+grep (или что другое) вполне пойдут. А вызывать их можно из батника

Comment: Я имел в виду описать некую логику в батнике, если tcp соединение есть в списке например nenstat-a выполнить одно действие, если нет, то другое.

Comment: Можно при помощи батника распарсить данные от нетстата и сделать вывод о соединении, но это изврат, конечно.

Comment: Используйте powershell или VBScript. Батники -- это прошлое тысячелетие. Они годятся только для самых простых вещей.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://windata.ru/windows-world/com/utilita-netstat/

С помощью батника можно вызвать любые программы, которые, в свою очередь, могут делать всё, что угодно :)
В последних ОС от Майкрософт можно, также, использовать VBScript, что весьма увеличивает возможности. Впрочем это уже не про батники....

Comment: Есть мнение, что powershell роднее для винды, чем vbscript, и в последних виндах является достойной заменой bat. Однако с ним есть ряд ньюансов.

Comment: Согласен с этим.